# How do I prevent automatic re-folding of python code after refactoring using vim with python-mode / rope and SimpylFold

Tags: python, vim, folding, python-mode, rope

I am using vim to create and edit python code. I have python-mode installed which provides (amongst other things) refactoring via rope. I also have SimpylFold installed to provide code folding.

Everything's working great apart from one annoying little thing...

When I do a refactoring operation, all folds are automatically closed immediately. This is super annoying as I have the folds set to various states of open / closed as appropriate for what I'm working on at the time and this undoes that so I have to re-open the folds that I'm working on.

Does anyone know / is anyone able to work out how I can prevent this so that I do the rafactoring operation and the folds remain as they were before please?

Cheers :)

Comment: what does `set fcl?` shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES! I did it!

My solution was:

- Install FastFold (https://github.com/Konfekt/FastFold) [1]
- Install vim-stay (https://github.com/kopischke/vim-stay) [2]. I'm not sure if this plugin is 100% necessary for this solution but it seems pretty useful anyway (e.g. persists folds after save, close, and re-open).
- Use the recommended settings for vim-stay, i.e. add `set viewoptions=cursor,folds,slash,unix` to `.vimrc`.
- Set the optional FastFold setting `let g:fastfold_savehook = 0` by adding it to `.vimrc`. This appears to be the crucial step that finally got it to work.

Happy days! Enjoy!

**UPDATE:** If you change the folds that you have open / closed since you opened the file, you have to save the *view* (not the file) using `:mkview` for those folds to persist after a refactoring [3].

Footnotes:

[1] I use Vundle (https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) so for me this was just a case of adding `Bundle 'Konfekt/FastFold'` to my `.vimrc`, saving, closing, re-opening, and then running `:BundleList` followed by `:BundleInstall`.

[2] Installation is the same as above but substitute `kopischke/vim-stay` for `Konfekt/FastFold`.

[3] I found this was easier when mapped to a key, in my case `<F9>`